# Accessing bundle configuration values from outside of the bundle

Tags: php, symfony

I added a [bundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/usage.md#step-3-configure-the-lifecycle-events-optional-step) to my application.  How can I access the `upload_destination` value (i.e. `/var/www/myapp/public/images/products`) by another service (i.e. `src/Controller/MyOtherService`)?

```
# config/packages/vich_uploader.yaml or app/config/config.yml
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        product_image:
            uri_prefix: /images/products
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/products'

            inject_on_load: false
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true
```

Comment: You can only access config values if the bundle directly exposes them.  You can use the 'app/console debug:container' commands to basically see what, if anything, is exposed.  But the most straight forward solution is to just add an upload_destination parameter to app/config/config.yml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can't.

You can only do so if whatever configuration parameter you want to "access" is accessible via a service provided by the bundle.

Not sure if the VichUploaderBundle exposes anything of the kind, but you the thing is... you don't really need it.

If such a value is needed by a different service, move it's value to an application parameter, a layer above the package configuration, and use that to inject in whatever service where you may need it:

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    vich_upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/products'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        bind:
            $vichUploadDestination: '%vich_upload_destination%'

### rest of the services definitions
```

Then in the package configuration:

```yaml
# config/packages/vich_uploader.yaml or app/config/config.yml
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
        mappings:
            product_image:
                uri_prefix: /images/products
                upload_destination: '%vich_upload_destination%'
# rest of the config
```

Then in any other services where you need this value, just add a string parameter to the constructor named `$vichUploadDestination`, and you'll be set:

```php
class MyService
{
    private string $vichUploadDestination;
    public function __construct(string $vichUploadDestination) {
        $this->vichUploadDestination = $vichUploadDestination;
    }
}
```

Symfony DI magic can be very convenient at times.

Comment: Thanks yivi,  Haven't tested it yet but am confident that this completely meets my needs.  Very new to Symfony and all its magic!  I see now how your approach is documented by https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-parameters, and better read the entire document in detail.